# Python - Searching from a multidimensional list and display it on a TKinter Widget

Tags: python, arrays, list, tkinter

This is my list:

```
contactlist = [
    ['Person1 Lastname1', '123123', 'Random City 1'],
    ['Person2 Lastname2', '246810', 'Random City 2'],
    ['Person3 Lastname3', '13579123', 'Random City 3'],
    ]
```

I have a TKinter Widget where the user can input a name and where the search result would be displayed.

```
Label(root,text = 'NAME',font = 'arial 12 bold',bg = 'SlateGray3').place(x=30,y=20)
Entry(root,textvariable = Name).place(x = 100,y = 20)
```

What i want to do is whenever the user inputs something in the widget (name), and then press the "search" button, it will display the full name in the widget. How do i do this?

Edit: More clarifcation on objective

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this program, just a raw interface you can style it yourself.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
contactlist = [
    ['Person1 Lastname1', '123123', 'Random City 1'],
    ['Person2 Lastname2', '246810', 'Random City 2'],
    ['Person3 Lastname3', '13579123', 'Random City 3'],
    ]
l1 = Label(root,text = 'Name')
l1.pack()
l2 = Label(root,text = 'Phn')
l2.pack()
l3 = Label(root,text = 'City')
l3.pack()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
def upd():
  global l1, l2, l3, e, contactlist
  resarr = [i for i in contactlist if i[0] == e.get()]
  if len(resarr)>0:
    l1.configure(text = resarr[0][0])
    l2.configure(text = resarr[0][1])
    l3.configure(text = resarr[0][2])
btn1 = Button(root, command=upd, text="Search")
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You can also replace

```
btn1 = Button(root, command=upd, text="Search")
btn1.pack()
```

with

```
e.bind("<KeyRelease>", upd)
```

To update contents automatically